# The name 'ascon1' does not exist in the current context // windows form app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, opc

so  i have created a program using TitaniumAS that connects to an OPC server and Write/Reads data from it. it works fine on console but i wanted to make a windows form app out of it to make it more practical. the thing is i can't access my methods/variables in the events (Button clicks...etc) and it says that the The name  does not exist in the current context.

Any suggestions ?

```
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Common;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Da;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Da.Browsing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;



namespace OPCtests
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {


            TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();

            Uri url = UrlBuilder.Build("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6");

            using (var server = new OpcDaServer(url))
            {
                server.Connect();

                OpcDaGroup group = server.AddGroup("MyGroup");
                group.IsActive = true;

                Ascon ascon1 = new Ascon();

                ascon1.ALM = ReadX("Channel1.Ascon1.AsconS");


                void WriteX(String Link, String Ascon)
                {
                    var definition1 = new OpcDaItemDefinition
                    {
                        ItemId = Link,
                        IsActive = true
                    };

                    OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = { definition1 };
                    OpcDaItemResult[] results = group.AddItems(definitions);



                    OpcDaItem tag = group.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == Link);
                    OpcDaItem[] items = { tag };

                    object[] Values = { Ascon };
                    HRESULT[] Results = group.Write(items, Values);

                }
                string ReadX(String Link)
                {
                    var definition1 = new OpcDaItemDefinition
                    {
                        ItemId = Link,
                        IsActive = true
                    };

                    OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = { definition1 };
                    OpcDaItemResult[] results = group.AddItems(definitions);
                    OpcDaItemValue[] values = group.Read(group.Items, OpcDaDataSource.Device);

                    return Convert.ToString(values[0].Value);


                }


            }

            InitializeComponent();

        }

       

        void Read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               textBox1.Text = ascon1.ALM;
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, is it time to take a look at the answer I provided?

Answer (score 2):

`Read_Click()` method is trying to access `ascon1`, but this variable is not in the current scope. `ascon1` is defined inside the `Form1` constructor, but it is not accessible from other methods in the `Form1` class. Declare your variable outside of the constructor

Comment: so i tried creating ascon1 outside the form constructor,i get a new error in my `  ascon1.ALM = ReadX("Channel1.Ascon1.AsconS")` it says :  CS8422 A static local function cannot contain a reference to 'this' or 'base'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "Ascon ascon1 = new Ascon();" in "public partial class Form1 : Form{ }". Regarding your "CS8422 Static local function cannot contain a reference to ’this‘ or ‘base’" error, it is because you added the "static" modifier after the local function. If your issue is not resolved, please share some information about "Ascon".